# Color identification in an image using opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors

![enter image description here][1]

Able to identify and get blue colour but culdnt identify the red colour range unable to fix colour range for red/purple stripes.I have used contour and created range for red,green,blue colour .That stripes colour range is not correct I tried settig maximum range for red/purple

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread(r'/home/pavithra/Downloads/pic.jpeg')

hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

# Set range for red color and  
red_lower = np.array([136, 86, 86], np.uint8) 
red_upper = np.array([239, 12, 50], np.uint8) 
red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, red_lower, red_upper) 


green_lower = np.array([25, 52, 72], np.uint8) 
green_upper = np.array([102, 255, 255], np.uint8) 
green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, green_lower, green_upper) 

blue_lower = np.array([94, 80, 2], np.uint8) 
blue_upper = np.array([120, 255, 255], np.uint8) 
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, blue_lower, blue_upper) 
    
kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8") 
red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, kernal) 
res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img,  
                            mask = red_mask) 
    
# For green color 
green_mask = cv2.dilate(green_mask, kernal) 
res_green = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, 
                            mask = green_mask) 
    
# For blue color 
blue_mask = cv2.dilate(blue_mask, kernal) 
res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, 
                            mask = blue_mask) 

# Creating contour to track red color 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(red_mask, 
                                        cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
      
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours): 
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour) 
    if(area > 300): 
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y),  
                                    (x + w, y + h),  
                                    (0, 255, 0), 2) 
            
        cv2.putText(img, "Red", (x, y), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, 
                    (0, 255, 0),2)     


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(green_mask, 
                                        cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
    
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours): 
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour) 
    if(area > 300): 
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y),  
                                    (x + w, y + h), 
                                    (0, 255, 0), 2) 
            
        cv2.putText(img, "Green", (x, y), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
                    1.0, (0, 255, 0),2) 


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blue_mask, 
                                        cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours): 
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour) 
    if(area > 300): 
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), 
                                    (x + w, y + h), 
                                    (255, 0, 0), 2) 
            
        cv2.putText(img, "Blue", (x, y), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                    1.0, (255, 0, 0),2) 
            
resize = cv2.resize(img, (800, 480))
cv2.imshow("All clg", resize) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hi Kavi, please make a distinction between your question and the code you have tried it helps people to read your code. We would also need to have a description the behavior of your current code and a question about the expected behavior.

Comment: I Need to detect the color of  stripes near the text in the images My expected output is TEXT=Covid 19 Ag,Stripe1=purple,stripe2=Red,Colour shuld be identified from the image

Comment: I need to print the color of thr stripe But the output gets masked so from there how to proceed

Comment: Hi Kavi, do all the labels you have both the colored stripes? Because the rightmost one seems to have only a single stripe and it is difficult to extract the colors in such cases. The text also seems to be difficult to be read by tesseract in every label as Vivian said. I have managed to separate the stripes in every label but am stuck at extracting the colors. I'll share the code now and will try to update it later.

Comment: And do all the labels have different text?

Comment: ya all labels will have text and two stripes one will be colloured always and othr may or may not b if its empty we an print as white color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split the image into half just to avoid unnecessary noise reductions. Then rotated the image to make the text horizontal. Binarized the image and obtained the three big blue-colored covid19 labels. Sorted them according to their y-coordinate (top to bottom). Performed some operations to obtain the region of interest (ROI, the two stripes which I named labels). Binarized each label to obtain the two contours of the colored stripes. Adjusted the gamma of the labels so that the colors become a little darker. Obtained the red-component of each stripe. Sorted them according to their x-coordinate (left to right). Assigned the stripe with the highest red value the red color, the other as purple.

Code:

```
    def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
        # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
        # their adjusted gamma values
        invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
        table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
            for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
        # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
        return cv2.LUT(image, table)

    def rotate(image: np.ndarray,angle, background_color): 
        old_width, old_height = image.shape[:2]
        angle_radian = math.radians(angle)
        width = abs(np.sin(angle_radian) * old_height) + abs(np.cos(angle_radian) * old_width)
        height = abs(np.sin(angle_radian) * old_width) + abs(np.cos(angle_radian) * old_height)
        image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
        rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)  
        rot_mat[1, 2] += (width - old_width) / 2
        rot_mat[0, 2] += (height - old_height) / 2
        return cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, (int(round(height)), int(round(width))), borderValue=background_color)

    img = cv2.imread("covid.jpg")
    rows,cols = img.shape[:2]
    img = img[:,:cols//2]
    rot = rotate(img,90,(255,255,255))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(rot,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    otsu = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(otsu,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,np.ones((3,3),np.uint8),iterations=3)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(opening,np.ones((1,5),np.uint8),iterations=5)
    dilate2 = cv2.dilate(dilate,np.ones((3,3),np.uint8),iterations=3)
    contours,_ = cv2.findContours(dilate2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    lables = [] # the three covid19 
    y_coords = [] # to sort the lables from top to bottom (the one with single color comes 1st)
    for cnt in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x = x + 10
        w = w - 20
        y_coords.append(y)
        lables.append(rot[y+h//3:y+h-h//3,x+w//2:x+int(w*0.70)])
    y_coords,lables = zip(*sorted(zip(y_coords,lables))) # sorting the lables from top to bottom
    y_coords = list(y_coords)
    lables = list(lables)

    otsus = []
    grays = []
    for image in lables:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grays.append(gray)
        mean = np.mean(gray)
        median = np.median(gray)
        otsus.append(cv2.threshold(gray,median-10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1])
    s = [] # just a list to store all the red and purple stripes
    for i in range(len(otsus)):
        otsus[i] = ~otsus[i]
        rows,cols = otsus[i].shape[:2]
        M = np.float32([[1,0,5],[0,1,5]])
        lables[i] = cv2.warpAffine(lables[i],M,(cols+5,rows+10)) # giving some padding
        
        # adjusting the gamma to make the colors more dark
        lables[i] = adjust_gamma(lables[i],gamma=0.40)
        
        otsus[i] = cv2.warpAffine(otsus[i],M,(cols+5,rows+10)) # same padding
        strips,_ = cv2.findContours(otsus[i],cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        x_coords = [] # to sort the red and purple stripes from left to right
        color = ["red","red"] # setting inital colors both to red 
        red_components = []
        for j in range(len(strips)):
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(strips[j])
            x_coords.append(x)
            # strip = lables[i][y:y+h,x:x+w,:]
            # strip = lables[i][y+h//4:y+h-h//4,x+w//4:x+w-w//4,:]
            strip = lables[i][y:y+h,x+w//5:x+w-w//5,:]
            s.append(strip)
            try:
                strip_color_b = int(np.mean(strip[0]))
                strip_color_g = int(np.mean(strip[1]))
                strip_color_r = int(np.mean(strip[2]))
                # strip_color = (strip_color_b,strip_color_g,strip_color_r)
                red = strip_color_r
                red_components.append(red)
            except IndexError:
                print("Lable number ",i,"has only a single color.")

        x_coords,red_components = zip(*sorted(zip(x_coords,red_components))) # simultaneously sorting the red and purple stripes from left to right 
        
        try:
            if red_components[0] < red_components[1]:
                color[0] = "purple"
            else:
                color[1] = "purple"
            # print("red components = ",red_components)
            print("Lable = ",i,"strip = ",0,"color = ",color[0])
            print("Lable = ",i,"strip = ",1,"color = ",color[1]) # LEFT to RIGHT
        except IndexError:
            print("Lable number ",i,"is excluded. Continuing with further labels.")

    print("TOTAL NUMBER OF LABLES = ",len(lables))   
        
    # reading the text
    custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 3'
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(otsu,config=custom_oem_psm_config))

    cv2.imshow("Lable 0",lables[0])
    cv2.imshow("Lable 1",lables[1])
    cv2.imshow("Lable 2",lables[2])
    cv2.imshow("rotated",rot)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Lable number  0 has only a single color.
Lable number  0 is excluded. Continuing with further labels.
Lable =  1 strip =  0 color =  purple
Lable =  1 strip =  1 color =  red
Lable =  2 strip =  0 color =  purple
Lable =  2 strip =  1 color =  red
TOTAL NUMBER OF LABLES =  3
COVID-19Aq
COVID-19Ag
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I get error "rotate is not defined" and your desired output value is blue color but I need the stripe color red or purple or mild red or empty.can you please help around it

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I haven't included the rotate function in the code. I will update my answer now.

Comment: I am sorry, it was difficult for me to search for that particular red and purple colors in the entire image. So I went for extracting the region of interest(the stripes). I think that code works fine for the image.

Comment: It doesnt give me any error or output when I run the code.I tried python image.py and run the code no output or error thrown

Comment: Oh, that's weird. It worked fine for me. And I think you have deleted that example picture from the question. Please add it so that it might be helpful if anyone wants to refer it in the future. And I recommend you to do a little more homework before asking.